# The value of $\iint_{A}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}$where $A$ is a loop of $r^{2}=a^{2}cos(2\theta)$

Tags: multiple-integral

The value of $\iint_{A}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}$,where $A$ is a loop of $r^{2}=a^{2}cos(2\theta)$ is to be calculated .

$\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{r=0}^{(a^{2}cos(2\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}+
\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}}\int_{r=0}^{(a^{2}cos(2\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{r=0}^{(a^{2}cos(2\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}+
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}}\int_{r=0}^{(a^{2}cos(2\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r dr d\theta}{({r^{2}+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

$=\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}
[({a^{2}cos(2\theta)+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}-a]
+\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}}
[({a^{2}cos(2\theta)+a^{2})}^{\frac{1}{2}}-a]$

$=a\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}
[({cos(2\theta)+1)}^{\frac{1}{2}}-1]
+a\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}}
[({cos(2\theta)+1)}^{\frac{1}{2}}-1]$

$=a\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}
[(2^{\frac{1}{2}}cos(\theta)-1]+
a\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}}
[(2^{\frac{1}{2}}cos(\theta)-1]$

$=[2a]+[-2\sqrt{2}a-\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$

Is it correct now.[image].

Comment: Here is your mistake: $\sqrt{r^2+a^2}|_0^{a\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}  = a\sqrt{\cos 2\theta - 1} - a$

Comment: One question. How do you define $r$ when $\cos 2\theta$ is negative?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz within the limits established for $\theta$ it is irrelevant.

Comment: And are you integrating on a closed loop or open path?

Comment: I am integrating inside shaded region.Please tell me how to integrate when $cos(2\theta)$ is negative.